# `with_items` output is too verbose

Tags: debugging, logging, ansible

I wrote an ansible task to iterate over a list of settings using `with_items`.  Now all my settings are logged when I run ansible.  It is very verbose and makes it hard to see what is happening.  But, if I disable all the output with `no_log`, I will have no way to identify specific items when they fail.

How could the output be improved — to show only an identifier for each item?

Example task:

```yaml
- authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item.user }}"
    key: "{{ item.key }}"
  with_items: "{{ ssh_keys }}"
```

Example output:

> ```
> TASK [sshkey-alan-sysop : ssh authorized keys] ********************************* 
>
> ok: [brick] => (item={u'user': u'alan-sysop', u'key': u'ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDAgRe16yLZa8vbzsrxUpT5MdHoEYYd/awAnEWML4g+YoUvLDKr+zwmu78ze/E1NSipoZejXpggUYRVhh8MOiCX6qpUguBDWZFlvSCE/7uXWWg7Oht0f1kDS2xU7YiycPIzMN1dmUEFY9AixnN936Dq6nOtEzgBwjo66I1YC/5jrsQEqF19shx43A4DTFlPUz/PnsqHl2ESrkIk3e8zyidaPN2pRbA5iKzdvPW4E2W2tKw9ll40vqRXzaWIF7v293Ostwi1IPi2erlC777DhjZUhZ1VGXIR7FDAfANzalrMe6c/ZysiXewiUYgMw0I8Dh1LK3QMj9Kuo35S5E0Xj3TB alan-sysop@alan-laptop'})
> ```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There's [loop_control](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#limiting-loop-output-with-label) for that:

```yaml
- authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item.user }}"
    key: "{{ item.key }}"
  with_items: "{{ ssh_keys }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.user }}"
```

Comment: Interesting!  So it wasn't just me, doing something dumb.  I notice this solution shows the full values under `-v`, whereas with my answer you have to use `-vvv` and look under `module_args`.  I don't think I can complain about the former... at least the `service` module is dumping about 4KB to the tty when run with `-v`.

Comment: the label is shorter, but ansible still prints out the item in the loop when using with debug.

Answer (score 1):

The identifiers can be used as keys of a dictionary.

```
- authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item }}"
    key: "{{ ssh_keys[item] }}"
  with_items: "{{ ssh_keys.keys() }}"
```

Example output:

```
TASK [sshkey-alan-sysop : ssh authorized keys] *********************************
ok: [brick] => (item=alan-sysop)
```