# Difficulties to loop over array result

Tags: ansible

I have to modified all bashrc files of all users on my linux servers.

I have this playbook to get all bashrc files :

```
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: List all bashrc in home directories
      ansible.builtin.find:
        path: /home/
        pattern: '*.bashrc'
        recurse: yes
        hidden: yes
        file_type: file
      register: files_matched

    - name: debug
      debug:
       var: item.path
      loop: "{{ files_matched.files }}"
```

The result is I have on my screen all values for all bashrc files like this :

```
TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [REDHAT7-DEV-01] => (item={u'rusr': True, u'uid': 0, u'rgrp': True, u'xoth': False, u'islnk': False, u'woth': False, u'nlink': 1, u'issock': False, u'mtime': 1556196786.966984, u'gr_name': u'root', u'path': u'/home/.bashrc', u'xusr': False, u'atime': 1556194629.8001442, u'inode': 12, u'isgid': False, u'size': 531, u'isdir': False, u'ctime': 1556196786.966984, u'isblk': False, u'wgrp': False, u'xgrp': False, u'isuid': False, u'dev': 64773, u'roth': True, u'isreg': True, u'isfifo': False, u'mode': u'0644', u'pw_name': u'root', u'gid': 0, u'ischr': False, u'wusr': True}) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "atime": 1556194629.8001442,
        "ctime": 1556196786.966984,
        "dev": 64773,
        "gid": 0,
        "gr_name": "root",
        "inode": 12,
        "isblk": false,
        "ischr": false,
        "isdir": false,
        "isfifo": false,
        "isgid": false,
        "islnk": false,
        "isreg": true,
        "issock": false,
        "isuid": false,
        "mode": "0644",
        "mtime": 1556196786.966984,
        "nlink": 1,
        "path": "/home/.bashrc",
        "pw_name": "root",
        "rgrp": true,
        "roth": true,
        "rusr": true,
        "size": 531,
        "uid": 0,
        "wgrp": false,
        "woth": false,
        "wusr": true,
        "xgrp": false,
        "xoth": false,
        "xusr": false
    },
    "item.path": "/home/.bashrc"
}
```

I have this for all users in /home/

When I do this

```
    - name: debug
      debug:
       var: files_matched
```

I have an array :

```
TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [REDHAT7-DEV-01] => {
    "files_matched": {
        "ansible_facts": {
            "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
        },
        "changed": false,
        "examined": 2268,
        "failed": false,
        "files": [
            {
                "atime": 1556194629.8001442,
                "ctime": 1556196786.966984,
                "dev": 64773,
                "gid": 0,
                "gr_name": "root",
                "inode": 12,
                "isblk": false,
                "ischr": false,
                "isdir": false,
                "isfifo": false,
                "isgid": false,
                "islnk": false,
                "isreg": true,
                "issock": false,
                "isuid": false,
                "mode": "0644",
                "mtime": 1556196786.966984,
                "nlink": 1,
                "path": "/home/.bashrc",
                "pw_name": "root",
                "rgrp": true,
                "roth": true,
                "rusr": true,
                "size": 531,
                "uid": 0,
                "wgrp": false,
                "woth": false,
                "wusr": true,
                "xgrp": false,
                "xoth": false,
                "xusr": false
            },
```

How I can have just the path in order to loop over it and add my modification ?
I have some difficulties with loop and array, I don't find a solution.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `loop: "{{ files_matched.files }}"`. Then in whatever task you need: `{{ item.path }}`.

Comment: This is pretty well explained in the documentation already: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#iterating-over-a-list-of-hashes

Comment: Also mind that, since Ansible is a Python application, one tends to speak about a **list** and not an _array_.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a modification on the last taks :

```
    - name: debug
      debug:
        msg: "path is {{ item.path }}."
      loop: "{{ files_matched.files }}"
```

I have what I want but I don't understand why I have all informations :

```
ok: [REDHAT7-DEV-01] => (item={u'rusr': True, u'uid': 0, u'rgrp': True, u'xoth': False, u'islnk': False, u'woth': False, u'nlink': 1, u'issock': False, u'mtime': 1666709700.946537, u'gr_name': u'root', u'path': u'/tmp/testdpi2.txt', u'xusr': False, u'atime': 1666709714.4843469, u'inode': 25, u'isgid': False, u'size': 14, u'isdir': False, u'ctime': 1666709700.946537, u'isblk': False, u'wgrp': False, u'xgrp': False, u'isuid': False, u'dev': 64775, u'roth': True, u'isreg': True, u'isfifo': False, u'mode': u'0644', u'pw_name': u'root', u'gid': 0, u'ischr': False, u'wusr': True}) => {
    "msg": "path is /tmp/testdpi2.txt."
}
ok: [REDHAT7-DEV-01] => (item={u'rusr': True, u'uid': 0, u'rgrp': True, u'xoth': False, u'islnk': False, u'woth': False, u'nlink': 1, u'issock': False, u'mtime': 1666709644.4183307, u'gr_name': u'root', u'path': u'/tmp/testdpi.txt', u'xusr': False, u'atime': 1666709706.733456, u'inode': 24, u'isgid': False, u'size': 6, u'isdir': False, u'ctime': 1666709644.4183307, u'isblk': False, u'wgrp': False, u'xgrp': False, u'isuid': False, u'dev': 64775, u'roth': True, u'isreg': True, u'isfifo': False, u'mode': u'0644', u'pw_name': u'root', u'gid': 0, u'ischr': False, u'wusr': True}) => {
    "msg": "path is /tmp/testdpi.txt."
}
ok: [REDHAT7-DEV-01] => (item={u'rusr': True, u'uid': 0, u'rgrp': True, u'xoth': False, u'islnk': False, u'woth': False, u'nlink': 1, u'issock': False, u'mtime': 1666709689.7376943, u'gr_name': u'root', u'path': u'/tmp/testdpi3.txt', u'xusr': False, u'atime': 1666709691.5566688, u'inode': 26, u'isgid': False, u'size': 21, u'isdir': False, u'ctime': 1666709689.7376943, u'isblk': False, u'wgrp': False, u'xgrp': False, u'isuid': False, u'dev': 64775, u'roth': True, u'isreg': True, u'isfifo': False, u'mode': u'0644', u'pw_name': u'root', u'gid': 0, u'ischr': False, u'wusr': True}) => {
    "msg": "path is /tmp/testdpi3.txt."
}
```

*item.path* is the variable I have to use to do my modification but how I can avoid the informations I don't want to see *((item={u'rusr': True, u'uid': 0, etc...)* ?

Comment: You are looking for the `label` of `loop_control`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42832731/2123530